# bootstrap collapsible option disable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Please check below example. when click the popup button, collapsible should not be work. how stop it.
html

```
    <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bar">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></i>Foo
        <button>
      Popup button
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- The inside div eliminates the 'jumping' animation. -->
    <div class="collapse" id="bar">
      Bar.
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/rvuzk3c2/1/)

Comment: means after click on popup button arrow button should disable ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to event in `click` function and add `stopPropagation`

```
$(".popup").click(function(e) {
  alert("fasfsa");
  e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLho9q26/1/